# Does std::condition_variable really unlock the given unique_lock object before blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, c++17, condition-variable

As the reference says: [1) Atomically unlocks lock, blocks the current executing thread, and...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)

I have below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex mutex_;
std::condition_variable condVar;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex_); //purposely global to check return of owns_lock() in main

void waitingForWork()
{
    std::cout << "Before wait, lck.owns_lock() = " << lck.owns_lock() << '\n';

    condVar.wait(lck);

    std::cout << "After wait, lck.owns_lock() = " << lck.owns_lock() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(waitingForWork);

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

  std::cout << "In main, lck.owns_lock() = " << lck.owns_lock() << '\n';
  condVar.notify_one();

  t1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using: `g++ with c++17 on ubuntu`

The output:

```
Before wait, lck.owns_lock() = 1
In main, lck.owns_lock() = 1
After wait, lck.owns_lock() = 1
```

But as per reference, I expected the mutex to get unlocked upon wait, i.e.:

```
In main, lck.owns_lock() = 0
```

Could someone please tell me why is it so ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read further:

> When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is reacquired and wait exits. If this function exits via exception, lock is also reacquired.

So it is always guaranteed that upon exit of wait, the lock is reacquired.

Comment: But I ask, why same is not observed through program ? The output is not aligned with the reference docs. The cout in main executes before exit of wait.

Comment: You actually have a data race in your code. You are accessing `lck` from two threads, but `std::unique_lock` is not designed for that. It is quite easy to check that `mutex_` has been unlocked: try to acquire the mutex in `main` right after the `sleep_for`.